# releasing file locks from OS X shell script

Tags: mac-osx, files

Files can be locked on OS X by going to the "Get Info" panel for the specific file and clicking the lock button.

I would need to remove locks from a shell script. What unix command can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlock "Locked" flag on a folder recursivly

chflags -R nouchg /folder/path

Answer (score 2):

Try `chflags nouchg YOUR_FILE`. To re-enable the lock, `chflags uchg YOUR_FILE`.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got xcode installed, `/Developer/Tools/SetFile`. To unlock:

```
% SetFile -a l <path>
```

To lock:

```
% SetFile -a L <path>
```

To query, you can use `/Developer/Tools/GetFileInfo`